# Why is injecting Endpoints etc. by CDI or Guice useful in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, cdi, guice, code-injection

my question is why is injecting, for example, Endpoints while using cdi and camel useful? Why cant we just simply create string describing the endpoint?

like here:

```
@Inject
@Uri("direct:inbound")
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@Inject
MockEndpoint outbound;

@Inject
@Uri("direct:inbound")
Endpoint endpoint;

@Inject
TypeConverter converter;
```

maybe injections provide some feature that we can somehow store the endpoint in injection's pool or something?

thanks for an answer
just starting with camel so please be mild :-)